# Spring cannot find app-config.xml from app-config-text.xml

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing, hsqldb

I am developing integration tests for DAO layer of my small app and have faced a problem. I use 2 different application-config.xml for testing (for using HSQLDB) and production (MySql).
Even though I imported my production config file in a testing one, Spring still cannot find it. As a result, no qualifying bean of type [DAO] found for dependency (hope, it is due to this issue).
Neither showing full path nor using **/ or / for xml files helped.

Exception I receive:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.phoneBook.DAO.ContactDAO] found for dependency
```

My test class:

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:**/application-context-test.xml"/*, "/application-config.xml"*/})
    @TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager",defaultRollback = true)
    @Transactional
    public class ContactTest {
    //various fields for tests  
@Inject
        private ContactDAO contactIntegrDAO;
        @Inject
        private UserDAO userItegrDAO;

// various test methods
}
```

In case I uncomment "/application-config.xml" in @ContextConfiguration my test configuration (with HSQLDB dataSource) doesn't start at all and I have all the integration tests invoked on production DB.

Test configuration in application-context-test.xml:

```
<import resource="classpath:**/application-config.xml"/>
```

Production configuration in application-config.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.phoneBook" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:properties/database.properties" />
</bean>
<!-- Alternative way to set database.properties -->
<!-- <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:properties\database.properties" 
    /> -->

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.phoneBook.entities" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop> 
            <prop key="hibernate.flushMode">${hibernate.flushMode}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
```

Structure of the project:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

**Update:**

Thanks to [asg's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2136086/asg) response I corrected misspelling of classpath, but, unfortunately, the problem remains

Answer (score 1):

Problem might be with your test application context.

Test configuration in application-context-test.xml:

```
<import resource="clathpath:**/application-config.xml"/>
```

Try changing it to:

Edited:

```
<import resource="classpath:application-config.xml"/>
```

You are importing 'src/resources/application-config.xml' xml file into the 'test/resources/application-config-test.xml' file.

So change your import statement to the above edited statement. It should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for a remark. Nevertheless, problem is the same/

Comment: I tried some examples. Please take a look and let me know if it works for you.